# Downloading excel file using php require(filename.php) results in corrupt file

Tags: php, download

I have a php file called downloadexcel.php used to download an xlsx file which looks like this

```
<?php
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=mod.xlsx');
header('Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
readfile('mod.xlsx');
exit;
```

When i access the php file directly using the url i download the excel file no problem.
But if i use

```
require( dirname(__FILE__).DS.'downloadexcel.php' );
```

Then it downloads the file but when i open i get error:
excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid.

It might be worth mentioning that the file is modified just before the download is triggered. Also the reason for not allowing direct access to the php file (or the excel file) is because only logged in administrators should have access to the excel file.

Has anyone got any idea how i can get this to work?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use PhpExcel. All of my excel problems went away. https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Comment: This probably means that the script where you're doing the require is outputting something (blank space, echoes/prints, BOM header, whatever) to the browser that then gets embedded in the data stream for the readfile.... open the file in a text editor and check

Comment: how are you modifying the file?

Comment: I am using PHPExcel to create/modify the file. The file on the server is not corrupt, only when i download it